# Personalizing chapter lines in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, chapters

I am using `scrbook` and would like to tune my table of contents to look like the one in this book : http://biblefacts.org/church/Charisma.pdf , with a text saying "Chapter #" on top of each entry.

I can't figure out how to do that. Currently, my code only shows a number in front of each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I've added the code to change (as requested in a comment) the format of the chapter headings.

To change the format of the chapter entries in the ToC ou can use the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package; to change the format of the chapter headings, you can use the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package. A little example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\scshape }
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{ Chapter\ }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\newline\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\cftdotfill{1}}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\itshape\raggedleft}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}
  {\normalfont\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{10pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How would I go about doing it for chapter headings as well (like on page 1 for example)?

Comment: @Raphink: I've added the requested modification to my example code; feel free to change it to suit your needs.

Comment: AFAIK usage of `titlesec` and `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the link to the example is not longer valid. So the following example may be a solution or not. Despite this problem, it shows several features of current KOMA-Script release.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix,toc=chapterentrywithdots]{scrbook}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  % Setting for the chapter heading:
  beforeskip=0pt plus 1pt,% distance before a chapter heading
  innerskip=10pt,% distance between "Chapter <nr>" and chapter title
  afterskip=20pt plus 2pt minus 1pt,% distance after chapter heading
  font=\Huge\normalfont,% font of chapter heading
  prefixfont=\Large\itshape,% change for the chapter number prefix line
  % Settings for the chapter entry to TOC
  tocbreakafternumber=true,% Line break after the number
  tocentrynumberformat=\chapterentrynumber,% use this command for number formatting
  tocentryformat=\relax,% reset the default font of the entry
  tocpagenumberformat=\relax,% reset the default font of the page number
  tocindent=1em,% indent the entry
]{chapter}
\newcommand*{\chapterentrynumber}[1]{%
  \textsc{\hspace{-1em}Chapter #1}% Set it in small caps with prefix Chapter
                                % and reskip the indent
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table of Contents]

[image: Chapter]